# How Can I Constantly Get an updated value from a variable from another script concurrently?

Tags: python, loops, mediapipe

Here is a code snippet of what I am doing. I am using mediapipe that looks at hands and maps their shape to certain things like if a hand is opened or closed. What I am doing is importing the mediapipe script (that works fine) into this code. I want to constantly get the updated value of "hand_sign_text_container" variable which tells me if the hand is open or closed. The issue is that it runs the app.py script to completion before it runs the while loop which is meant to get the updated value every time. How can I constantly obtain values while running the loop?

```
import app
import time

def main():
    app.main()
    return app.hand_sign_text_container[0]

def position():
    pos = main()
    if pos == "Open":
        return 2
    elif pos == "Close":
        return 1

while(1):
    pos = position()
    if pos == 2:
        print("Open")
    elif pos == 1:
        print("Close")
```

The only thing I can think of is combining this code with the app.py script. Is there no other way?

Comment: There is another way, called inter-process communication (IPC). You could set up the script so that a variable gets updated whenever it receives a message to that effect from the other script, and for such a message to get sent automatically when the variable gets updated in the other script. However, that's a lot of coding, hard to test and debug, and really to be avoided unless your use case really, really needs it. What exactly are you looking to do? There's probably a better way, like integrating the scripts, having one script call the other, or using something like a database.